# JUnit4 @Test(expected=MyException.class) VS try/catch

Tags: java, exception, junit4

I'm pondering on exception handling and unit tests best practices because we're trying to get some code best practices in place.

A previous article regarding best practices, found on our company wiki, stated "Do not use try/catch, but use Junit4 @Test(expect=MyException.class)", without further information. I'm not convinced.

Many of our custom exception have an Enum in order to identify the failure cause.
As a result, I would rather see a test like :

```
@Test
public void testDoSomethingFailsBecauseZzz() {
try{
   doSomething();
} catch(OurCustomException e){
   assertEquals("Omg it failed, but not like we planned", FailureEnum.ZZZ, e.getFailure());
}
}
```

than :

```
@Test(expected = OurCustomException.class)
public void testDoSomethingFailsBecauseZzz() {
   doSomething();
}
```

when doSomethig() looks like :

```
public void doSomething throws OurCustomException {
  if(Aaa) {
     throw OurCustomException(FailureEnum.AAA);
  } 
  if(Zzz) {
     throw OurCustomException(FailureEnum.ZZZ);
  }
  // ...
}
```

On a side note, I am more than convinced that on some cases @Test(expected=blabla.class) IS the best choice (for example when the exception is precise and there can be no doubt about what's causing it).

Am I missing something here or should I push the use of try/catch when necessary ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you simply want to check that an exception of a certain type was thrown, use the annotation's `expected` property.
- If you want to check properties of the thrown exception (e.g. the message, or a custom member value), catch it in the test and make assertions.

In your case, it seems like you want the latter (to assert that the exception has a certain `FailureEnum` value); **there's nothing wrong with using the `try/catch`**.

The generalization that you should "not use try/catch" (interpreted as "never") is bunk.

*Jeff is right though; the organization of your exception hierarchy is suspect. However, you seem to recognize this. :)*

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm rather happy when I see you guys saying that the exception hierarchy is suspect, it has been bothering me for a while. (IT may be why I am pondering on these issues ;)). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your enum is being used as an alternative to an exception hierarchy?  Perhaps if you had an exception hierarchy the `@Test(expected=XYZ.class)` would become more useful?

Comment: Yeah, they really like Enum and String attributes instead of a real object-oriented code ;) That may be one of the root of all evil in some of our exception handling code ;)

Comment: If you're pondering the best practices why not consider re-factoring to an exception hierarchy?  Making it more useful and maintainable in the future?

Comment: Hmm refactoring of the whole application is sadly not possible right now. Eventually it's going to be needed, but I don't have that kind of power or time ;) However, if I ever have to start a project from scratch or help with the refactoring, I will certainly push the use of a correct exception hierarchy :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the raw exception type, then the `expected` method is appropriate. Otherwise, if you need to test something about the exception (and regardless of the `enum` weirdness testing the message content is common) you can do the try catch, but that is a bit old-school. The new JUnit way to do it is with a `MethodRule`. The one that comes in the API (`ExpectedException`) is about testing the message specifically, but you can easily look at the code and adapt that implementation to check for failure `enum`s.

Comment: Hmm. MethodRule, I have never heard about. That's something I was missing ;) Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In your special case, you want to test (1) if the expected exception *type* is thrown and (2) if the error number is correct, because the method can thrown the same exception with different types.

This requires an inspection of the exception object. But, you can stick to the recommendation *and* verify that the right exception has been thrown:

```
@Test(expected = OurCustomException.class)
public void testDoSomethingFailsBecauseZzz() {
   try {
      doSomething();
   } catch (OurCustomException e) {
      if (e.getFailureEnum.equals(FailureEnum.ZZZ))  // use *your* method here
         throw e;

      fail("Catched OurCostomException with unexpected failure number: " 
        + e.getFailureEnum().getValue());  // again: your enum method here
   }
}
```

<strike>This pattern will *eat* the unexpected exception and make the test fail.</strike>

**Edit**

Changed it because I missed the obvious: we can make a test case fail and capture a message. So now: the test passes, if the expected exception *with* the expected error code is thrown. If the test fails because we got an unexpected error, then we can read the error code.

Comment: Don't we want to avoid eating unexpected exceptions ? Also, I don't really want to stick to the recommandation (but if I have to, I like your solution) ;)

Comment: @Stph - thanks for your comment, I've improved my answer. Simply forgot, that we can make it fail with a fail message ;)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this when searching how to handle exceptions.

As @Yishai mentioned, the preferred way to expect exceptions is using JUnit rules and  `ExpectedException`.

When using `@Test(expected=SomeException.class)` a test method will pass if the exception is thrown anywhere in the method.

When you use `ExpectedException`:

```
@Test
public void testException()
{
    // If SomeException is thrown here, the test will fail.
    expectedException.expect(SomeException.class);
    // If SomeException is thrown here, the test will pass.
}
```

You can also test:

- an expected message: `ExpectedException.expectMessage()`;
- an expected cause: `expectedException.expectCause()`.

As a side note: I don't think using enums for exception messages/causes is good practice. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

I made [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) because I was facing the same problem as you did, Stph.
With catch-exception your code could look like this:

```
@Test
public void testDoSomethingFailsBecauseZzz() {
   verifyException(myObj, OurCustomException.class).doSomething();
   assertEquals("Omg it failed, but not like we planned", FailureEnum.ZZZ,    
               ((OurCustomException)caughtException()).getFailure() ;
}
```